# Can Microsoft Translator Service take context as a parameter for translation?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am wondering if [Microsoft Translator Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/) can take context as a parameter for translation.
For example, I want to translate the word "run" as in "run a computer program", but not "run on a track".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Translate with context
2. Retrieve the translated phrase that aligns with the word in question: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/translator/word-alignment

Be prepared for the operation to fail: There aren't always 1:1 translations of individual words. Works only from and to English.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I need. Next, I will try to find out how to do it with the beloved WindowsCommunityToolkit.