# Why does context make the translation of a word by Microsoft Translator Service worse?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I was hoping context would make the translation by Microsoft Translator Service more accurate, but I have found the following case showing the context makes the translation unusable.
"Siren" alone is translated to "警笛" correctly by Microsoft Translator Service:
[image]

However, adding some context makes it be translated to "天狼星" that has nothing to do with "siren".
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this post for text context <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512784/can-microsoft-translator-service-take-context-as-a-parameter-for-translation>

Comment: Not sure how that question helps.  BTW, I asked that question.